# Understanding how directive priority level work in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**`app.js`** is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.directive('myDirective2', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 100,
        //template:"<h1>myDirective2</h1>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $transclude,$timeout) {
            //$scope.name = "executed myDirective2";
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.name = "executed myDirective2";
            }, 3000);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('myDirective3', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 200,
        //template:"<h1>myDirective3</h1>",
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $transclude, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.name = "executed myDirective3";
            }, 3000);
        }
    };
});
```

And **`index.html`** is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div my-directive3 my-directive2></div>
        <br/>
        Name:{{name}}

    </body>
</html>
```

Though priority for `my-directive2` is lesser than `my-directive3` still why `my-directive2` is getting executed? Should not it be the directive with higher priority which in this case is `my-directive3`?

Answer (score 15):

Priority is a number for which directive gets executed **first** in case of multiple priorities. Basically you use it to determine the order of execution, not to exclude other directives.

> Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

You can read more about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206060402/http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/).